# Use grep to get next word after match

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I want to use grep to get a number from a JSON file
For example, I want to get the **1.0872** from this:

```
{"base":"EUR","date":"2016-03-01","rates":{"USD":1.0872}}
```

Using

```
grep "USD" rates
```

gives out the whole line

```
{"base":"EUR","date":"2016-03-01","rates":{"USD":1.0872}}
```

I just want to display  **1.0872**.

I tried using a regex but it doesn't work (probably an error on my part since I've never done this before):

```
grep -oP '(?<="USD"\:)\w+' file
```

Comment: For a start \w+ won't give you 1.0872 because '.' is not classed in \w. try changing it to [\d\.]+. It won't fix the whole problem but it should help.

Comment: Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/Mk5Ctx), try `grep -oP '(?<="USD":)[\d.]+' file`. Or `grep -oP '(?<="USD":)\d*\.?\d+' file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "normal" integers and float values, you may use

```
grep -oP '(?<="USD":)\d+(?:\.\d+)?' file
```

If your numbers can have no integer part and can start with a `.`, use

```
grep -oP '(?<="USD":)\d*\.?\d+' file
```

An optional `-`:

```
grep -oP '(?<="USD":)-?\d*\.?\d+' file
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/q1019b)